# Suggested TargetFrameworks

Tags: .net, nuget

I'd like to release a public nuget package for general consumption by the .NET community. Does anyone have a suggested list of TargetFrameworks that they would recommend? Is something like this too broad or redundant?

```
<TargetFrameworks>net48;net472;net452;net40;net35;net20;netstandard2.0;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is likely to be too broad - if it's a library and it can target `netstandard2.1` then that's probably enough. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#target-net-standard